# Prevent page reload on back button (use cache). Or scroll user back down. (Issue on, at least, iPhone)

Tags: javascript, html, browser-history

Is is possible to *prevent* a page from being reloaded when a user clicks the browser back button? Or at least make sure that the page is scrolled down like it was before?

My webpage shows a list of items. The user scrolls down and then clicks on an item to go to another page. When they then click the back button, I want them to be back on the original page, scrolled down.

This works fine on my desktop (Windows, Chrome), but on my iPhone (iOS7, Safari and Chrome) it reloads the page, which, first of all, takes time and is annoying. Chrome then scrolls back down, but Safari does not, which means that the user is back at the top. The behavior, actually, doesn't seem to be quite consistent.

Is this just a decision made by the browser? It also reloads the page after the screen has been locked and then unlocked. (Again, I'm trying on the iPhone.) Or is it something about my html/header/js that could be doing it?

I'm thinking that I can use HTML caching and then, on the page itself, keep track of how far the user has scrolled. Then when the page is reloaded from cache, I can make it scroll down to where it was before. Is that really the way to go?

It looks like www.amazon.com has got it working, so there must be some solution.

Comment: did you ever find your answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to avoid "reload", but several other reasons can make the page reload on mobiles.

I recommend that instead of trying to avoid the reload, you save user data using cookies, or better [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage).

For example you want to save the last page position (position of the scroll bar):

```
(function () {
    var scrollFired = false;

    function saveScroll () {
        if (window.localStorage) {
            window.localStorage.setItem("scrollLeftTop", window.pageXOffset + "," + window.pageYOffset);
        }
    }

    function autoScroll() {
        scrollFired = true;
        if (window.localStorage) {
            var xy = window.localStorage.getItem("scrollLeftTop");
            if (xy) {
                var a = xy.split(",");
                var x = a[0];
                var y = a[1];
                window.scroll(x, y);
            }
        }
    }

    function onLoadAutoScroll() {
       if(scrollFired === false) {//Prevent scroll if run DOMContentLoaded
          autoScroll();
       }
    }

    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", autoScroll, false);
    window.addEventListener("load", onLoadAutoScroll, false);//If DOMContentLoaded not "run"
    window.addEventListener("scroll", saveScroll, false);
})();
```

### Compatibility

Note: If needs `localStorage` in older browsers, try (cookies like localStorage):

```
if (!window.localStorage) {
  window.localStorage = {
    getItem: function (sKey) {
      if (!sKey || !this.hasOwnProperty(sKey)) { return null; }
      return unescape(document.cookie.replace(new RegExp("(?:^|.*;\\s*)" + escape(sKey).replace(/[\-\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "\\s*\\=\\s*((?:[^;](?!;))*[^;]?).*"), "$1"));
    },
    key: function (nKeyId) {
      return unescape(document.cookie.replace(/\s*\=(?:.(?!;))*$/, "").split(/\s*\=(?:[^;](?!;))*[^;]?;\s*/)[nKeyId]);
    },
    setItem: function (sKey, sValue) {
      if(!sKey) { return; }
      document.cookie = escape(sKey) + "=" + escape(sValue) + "; expires=Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 GMT; path=/";
      this.length = document.cookie.match(/\=/g).length;
    },
    length: 0,
    removeItem: function (sKey) {
      if (!sKey || !this.hasOwnProperty(sKey)) { return; }
      document.cookie = escape(sKey) + "=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT; path=/";
      this.length--;
    },
    hasOwnProperty: function (sKey) {
      return (new RegExp("(?:^|;\\s*)" + escape(sKey).replace(/[\-\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "\\s*\\=")).test(document.cookie);
    }
  };
  window.localStorage.length = (document.cookie.match(/\=/g) || window.localStorage).length;
}
```

Comment: But Amazon seems to have found a solution that prevents reloading. I can use the back button even when I turn off my wifi, also on the iPhone.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out. It was actually my own site's javascript that was causing a reload.

Comment: Strangely my comment disappeared. But I'm glad you found the "problem" and solved. I wish you success.

Comment: @user984003 what's the reason of your problem, I encounter same issue

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe you can "prevent a page from being reloaded when a user clicks the browser back button" (as your question begins). The user should have final say in where their browser navigates.

You could bind a function to the `beforeunload` event, and in that function you could put an alert that would delay the user's press of `back` or `reload` with a chance for them to read a custom message and choose to proceed or cancel.

Here that is in jQuery:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
  return 'Are you sure?';
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload

If your concern is more simply reloading a cached-and-scrolled version of the previous page, rather than executing a completely fresh reload…that sounds more like either a setting on your content server and/or a setting on the user's browser.

I know with my registrar/host I can log in and access a GUI cache control, or I could upload custom cache instructions in my `.htaccess` file. These would control whether the user is allowed to cache files from your server, and for how long, as I understand. The user's web browser, too, should have settings for whether to cache files or to load-fresh every time.

Comment: I do want the user to be able to use the back button. What I want, is to prevent this 'back page' being reloaded when it is shown again.